# Azure Table Service REST API: JSON format is not supported

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to request a line from Azure Table Storage using the REST API and C++, but always got the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <cod_e>JsonFormatNotSupported</cod_e>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">JSON format is not supported.
RequestId:0ccb3b9b-0002-0029-3389-0d2fa1000000
Time:2016-09-13T06:39:13.3155742Z</message>
</error>
```

Here is my request:

```
GET https://<myaccount>.table.core.windows.net/<mytable>(PartitionKey='<mypartition>',RowKey='<myrow>')?<sharedsignature>
```

Here how I fill request headers, as from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx:

```
std::string sharedAccessSignature("<sharedsignature>");
std::string dateTime(GetDateTime());
std::string stringToSign(dateTime + "\n/" + account + "/" + "<mytable>");
std::string request("(PartitionKey='<mypartition>',RowKey='<myrow>')");
stringToSign += request;
std::string signatureString(HMACSHA256(stringToSign, sharedAccessSignature));

headers["Authorization"] = "SharedKeyLite " + account + ":" + signatureString;
headers["DataServiceVersion"] = "3.0;NetFx";
headers["MaxDataServiceVersion"] = "3.0;NetFx";
headers["x-ms-version"] = "2015-12-11";
headers["x-ms-date"] = dateTime;
headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
headers["Accept-Charset"] = "UTF-8";
```

The table exists and is not empty.
Please advise what's wrong?

**Update 1**
Removing `sharedsignature` from request, i.e. `GET https://<myaccount>.table.core.windows.net/<mytable>(PartitionKey='<mypartition>',RowKey='<myrow>')` leads to the same result.
Removing `Authorization` header from the request leads to the same result too.

**Update 2**
Putting `https://<myaccount>.table.core.windows.net/<mytable>(PartitionKey='<mypartition>',RowKey='<myrow>')?<sharedsignature>` in a browser produces a valid response, but in *Atom* format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry 
  xml:base="https://<myaccount>.table.core.windows.net/" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
  m:etag="W/&quot;datetime'2016-09-13T05%3A29%3A51.211538Z'&quot;">
  <id>https://<myaccount>.table.core.windows.net/<mytable> (PartitionKey='<mypartition>',RowKey='<myrow>')</id>
  <category term="<myaccount>.<mytable>" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <link rel="edit" title="<mytable>" href="<mytable> (PartitionKey='<mypartition>',RowKey='<myrow>')" />
  <title />
  <updated>2016-09-13T11:25:19Z</updated>
  <author><name /></author>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:PartitionKey><mypartition></d:PartitionKey>
      <d:RowKey><myrow></d:RowKey>
      <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-09-13T05:29:51.211538Z</d:Timestamp>
      <d:Score m:type="Edm.Int32">1050</d:Score>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

**Update 3**
Investigation situation using `curl` I found that adding `Accept: application/json;odata=fullmetadata` to the request headers leads to the error above. Default `Accept */*` in headers produces valid *Atom* response.

Comment: Instead of this `headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";`, please use `headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=fullmetadata";`. Also, I am not sure why are you appending `<sharedsignature>`? I don't think it is needed.

Comment: @GauravMantri: Changing `Accept` header as you proposed leads to the same result. 
When I remove `?<sharedsignature>` part from `GET` request I got `ResourceNotFound` error: `The specified resource does not exist`.

Comment: What's this `sharedAccessSignature` in your code? Is it SAS Token? Please note that if you're using Shared Access Signature, you need not calculate/define `Authorization` header as the authorization information is included in your SAS token itself (`sig`).

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, this is SAS token. But without `Authorization` header situation is the same.

Comment: `But without Authorization header situation is the same` -> This is weird. Would you mind updating your question after all the changes you have done so that we can see what's going on with your code.

Comment: @GauravMantri I've edited the question.

Comment: What about using the c++ api, here are the samples https://github.com/azure-samples/storage-table-cpp-getting-started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, got it!
The issue was in my shared signature.
While looking at it I found `sv=2012-02-12` part, and assumed, that it means API version. The version, *before* JSON support was introduced! I created a new shared signature and finally got JSON with the following curl command.
`curl -v -H "Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata" -H "x-ms-version: 2015-12-11" "https://<myaccount>.table.core.windows.net/<mytable>(PartitionKey='<mypartition>',RowKey='<myrow>')?<mysharedsignature>"`

So, for everyone, who face the same issue in the future: please check your signature first!